# Shellshock exploit on Linux Routers/Modems?

Tags: shellshock, router

I am worried about the millions (actually, worried about mine) of routers/modems that run Linux. How exposed are they to Shellshock?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most Linux-based routers are running an [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/)/[DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) derivative.  These routers use [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/) as their shell (Bash is much too heavyweight for the hardware), and consequently are not vulnerable.

Comment: Here is a [post](https://blog.pfsense.org/?p=1457) from pfsense too. "The base system of pfSense does not include bash."

Comment: Is there a way to test if my own router is vulnerable?

Comment: "Most Linux-based routers are running an OpenWRT/DD-WRT derivative." - lolwut? And busybox is not a shell.

Comment: @SmitJohnth, busybox is a multi-call binary that encapsulates most of what you need to run a command-line Linux into a single executable.  Run it under the name `sh` or `ash`, and you get a shell derived from `ash`.

Comment: @Mark So busybox is not a shell but a wrapper for ash, am I right?

Comment: @SmitJohnth, Sort of maybe if you squint at it right.

Comment: @Mark sort of maybe? It uses ash or other shell, so it would be vulnerable only if ash or this other shell would be vulnerable.

Comment: From the OpenWRT website: The OpenWrt standard unix shell is the Busybox-fork of the Debian implementation of the Almquist shell (see → https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/ash/#busybox). In case you want to read about it.

Answer (score 4):

Ubiquiti Routers running EdgeOS have much beefier hardware, and run a derivative of Vayatta on Linux that includes bash. Those are likely vulnerable.

http://community.ubnt.com/t5/EdgeMAX/Re-Bash-shell-vuln-Is-ER-also-vulnerable/m-p/1024785

Answer (score 1):

Endian Community Firewall is also currently vulnerable, even though they have already released a patch for their paying customers.  Planning on switching to Sophos UTM soon.